# Вопрос безопасности: доступ ajax к php по ключу

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, безопасность

Есть веб-страница с формой, ajax'ом отправляю параметры php-скрипту, который удаляет в mysql данные и формирует ответ странице. Пример запроса:

```
query.php?one=1&two=5
```

Получается, что можно вручную в адресной строке ввести этот адрес с любыми параметрами и потереть мне базу. Знаю что разные api поддерживают ключи, но как я его отправлю ajax'ом, ведь он тогда будет виден в исходном коде.

Как в этой связке сделать проверку ключа?

Comment: Как у вас авторизуется пользователь?

Comment: @Sergiks авторизация в index.php, в нем javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользователю в момент авторизации обычно дают какую-то роль с различными правами. Если роль имеет права на удаление, она видит в браузере и ajax и стороне сервере может удалять после проверки на соответствие прав. Что - вроде `<? if ($_SESSION['userpower'] == 'necro') { /*Действие для админа*/ } else { exit(); } ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос интересный.

С одной стороны непонятно с чего вдруг злоумышленику будут доступны исходные коды. Или вы показываете функционал удаления данных всем подряд, кто заходит на сайт?

С другой стороны вы правы. Такой подход абсолютно небезопасен и надо что-то делать. Обычно это решается механизмом авторизации. И удалять данные разрешают только авторизованному пользователю. Или определенному кругу авторизованных пользователей.

И проверку делают как на клиенте (кому показывать функционал удаления), так и на стороне сервера (что запрос пришел от авторизованного пользователя и что ему разрешено удалять)

Comment: полагаю да, частично защита есть, авторизация к index.php, в котором виден javascript, в котором видно к какому php-скрипту идет обращение и с какими параметрами. Но. Уже неоднократно обсуждалось, что боты яшек/гоголей лазят по страницам админки, которые они знать не могут. Они могут вставлять отслеживалки в различные плагины браузеров и видеть мои скрипты и параметры, с которыми обращаются к скриптам.

Comment: @Jean-Claude боты не могут лазить по админке, если вход в админку по логину и паролю. Бот - это как человек, но без тела. Ему тоже нужны права. без знания паролей он как обиженная девочка расплачется и побежит жаловаться подружке, что вы ему не доверяете.. и всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  я про это searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=918168

Comment: @newman а как мне проверить, что запрос пришел от авторизированного пользователя, если index.php (панель) и query.php (формирует json и удаляет mysql строки) никак не связаны?

Comment: @Jean-Claude любым способом проверки авторизации, коих в гугле очень-очень много. Простейший — выдать пользователю строку из случайных буквоцифр, сохранить её себе в БД, а пользователю в cookies. С запросами пользователь будет присылать эту строку, по ней можно обратиться к БД, откуда узнать, какой это пользователь, и таким образом проверить доступ. Есть ещё более изощрённые и гибкие вроде зашифрованных сессий и jwtoken, но это встречается реже. (хм, может в ответ вынести?)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Кстати, конкретно в php для вышеописанного ещё есть механизм сессий с буквоцифрами в `PHPSESSID`, в гугле тоже информации навалом

Comment: @andreymal про куки не подумал, попробую реализовать это так.